# Verify a proof that every $T_1$-space is a $T_0$-space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

How's my proof? Are there any unnecessary things to be cut out, or missing details to be added? Did I misuse any notation?

[image]

My biggest doubts would be:
Is writing out the elements of $τ$ like I did necessary? Is the notation correct?
Am I using the word "arbitrary" correctly?

Comment: What is your definition of a $T_0$ space and a $T_1$ space?

Comment: A $T_0$-space is a topological space such that for each pair of distinct points $a$, $b$ in $X$, either there exists an open set containing $a$ and not $b$, or there exists an open set containing $b$ and not $a$.

Comment: A $T_1$-space is a topological space such that every singleton set $\{x\}$ is closed

Comment: Don't think you need to bring in the complexity of an indexed set. Pick two arbitrary elements $x$, $y$ of $T = (X, \tau)$, prove that you can always find a set in $\tau$ that hasn't got both $x$ and $y$ in but has either $x$ or $y$ in.

Comment: Would you say that the proof is correct but too long-winded?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/ .

Answer (score 1):

Follow the definitions. A $T_{1}$ space is a space in which for every pair of points each one of them has a neighborhood not containing the other point.

A $T_{0}$ space (as defined by Kolmogorov) is a space in which for every pair of points at least one of them has a neighborhood not containing the other.

So the statement if $T_{1}$ then $T_{0}$ is obvious by the definitions!

Comment: I haven't read up on neighbourhoods yet. Maybe the textbook will cover that later :p

Comment: See Simmon's: Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis! Very good!